# Find if Stored Procedure Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, stored-procedures, error-handling

Is there a method in T-SQL to see if error occurred in Stored Procedure, without the use of @Output or try catch?

We have a lot of legacy code 200+ stored procedures. I have seen @Output method and try catch, however we would have to refactor legacy code, which may break. Just curious, if there is a way to catch error without changing old code.

```
declare @TestErrorFlag bit -- or can be int or varchar(255)

-- trying to do something similar to this
set @TestErrorFlag  = if error(exec dbo.testprocedure)

Trying to store in some type of indicator variable

@TestErrorFlag = 1 if procedure succeeds, 
@TestErrorFlag = 0 if procedure fails
```

Comment: `if error(exec sp)` is the same as `try exec sp catch`. My SP returns 0 if everything went well and other value, usually a negative value, if went wrong.

Comment: So like this, declare @@testvalue int

set @@testvalue = iferror (exec dbo.testprocedure), had to use two ampersands, so it would not ping user

Comment: When your stored procedures have errors, do you raise exceptions? `RETURN <int>;` where `<int> != 0`, or...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an error condition in your stored procedure raises an exception, your only option without changing the code inside the procedure, really, is to wrap the call in `try`/`catch`:

```
BEGIN TRY;
  EXEC sys.sp_helpdb @foo = 1;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
END CATCH;
```

If your procedure returns an error number without bubbling up an exception, e.g.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.bob
  @fail bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@fail = 1)
  BEGIN
    RETURN -1;
  END
  -- unnecessary, but:
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    RETURN 0;
  END
END
```

Then you can use this format:

```
DECLARE @TestErrorFlag int;
EXEC @TestErrorFlag= dbo.bob @fail = 1;
PRINT @TestErrorFlag;
```

Of course in this case if any error condition in the procedure *does* lead to an exception, the `PRINT` won't happen.

---

Error handling is a **massive** topic. I would browse around these articles:

- [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server - Part 1](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html)
- [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server - Part 2](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html)
- [Error and Transaction Handling in SQL Server - Part 3](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part3.html)

Comment: What fist line? Copy what result? I’m not sure I understand which code sample you’re talking about.